# Gremlin python coalesce for edges

Tags: python, gremlin, coalesce

I have written a script to avoid creating duplicates for vertex and edges but I have some troubles with edges.
This is the script:

```
g.V().has('dog', 'name', 'pluto').fold().\
    coalesce(__.unfold(), __.addV('dog').property('name', 'pluto')).store('dog').\
    V().has('person', 'name', 'sam').fold().\
    coalesce(__.unfold(), __.addV('person').property('name', 'sam')).store('person').\
    select('person').unfold().\
    coalesce(__.outE('has_dog').where(__.inV().has(T.id, __.select('dog').unfold().id())),
             __.addE('has_dog').to(__.select('person').unfold())).toList()
```

With this, I create the new two vertex and the new edge. If I execute it again, no new vertex and edge is created. For now all it's ok.

If I change 'pluto' with 'charlie' to create a new 'dog' vertex, this script creates the new vertex but return the previous edge created with 'pluto'. So if that 'person' already has that relationship, the script not creates a new one.

The thing I don't understand, it's that the code

```
__.select('dog').unfold().id()
```

should return the id of the new/old 'dog' vertex and check if the edge with 'person' exists.
If I execute that script to get the id and I replace that script with the id, for example

```
__.outE('has_dog').where(__.inV().has(T.id, 42))
```

the script works correctly and creates the edge with the new 'dog' vertex.

Why with the script to get id doesn't work but with the integer works? It's no sense because I should have the same result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have run into is that a `has` step cannot take an arbitrary traversal but a `where` step can. You just need to reformulate the `has` step as a `where` step. An arbitrary traversal inside a `has` step is treated as "true" if it returns any result. This is one of those Gremlin things that looks as if it should work but actually does not.

Here is a contrived example that shows the `where...by` pattern that should be helpful in your case.

```
gremlin> g.V(3).as('x').V().where(eq('x')).by(id)
==>v[3]
```

As you are using `store` the `where` step becomes something like this

```
gremlin> g.V(3).store('x').V().where(eq('x')).by(id).by(unfold().id())
==>v[3]
```

So the line in your code will end up something like this

```
filter(__.inV().where(eq('dog')).by(T.id).by(unfold().id()))
```

Comment: I test your solution as follow:

    __.outE('has_dog').where(__.inV().where(eq(__.select('dog').unfold()).by(T.id))

but I get an error: GremlinServerError: 599: null: .where(P)

Comment: Remove the `select` from inside the `eq` it is not needed - that usage of where will implicitly select the thing stored as `dog`.

Comment: I have tried also without 'select' but it doesn't work because 'dog' is a BulkSet and not an element.
Gremlin give me the error: GremlinServerError: 500: class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.BulkSet cannot be cast to class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element

Comment: That is why I have the `unfold` in my example and the order of the `by` steps is important. The first one refers to the value that flows in to the `where` the second one to `dog`. Notice in my example how I have two `by` steps.